# How to change a commit message in hg mq?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-queue

I have added 4 patches to my workspace.
While creating these patches, I had used `qnew -m "<commit-message>"`. Now I noticed that I have not given proper commit message. How to modify **all** the commit messages?

I tried few things:
`$ hg ci`;
`abort: cannot commit over an applied mq patch`

`$ hg qci`
`abort: no queue repository`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only to the last applied patch on the queue via `qrefresh`. If you need to change all of the commit messages in the same way, e.g. adding an issue in front of the message, then you can write a script that would do it. Let's assume you have all you patches applied, then we will `qref` a patch and then `qpop` it until all of them changed. `qheader` will give you a message of the top patch. So using bash your script would roughly look as follows:

```
amendment="ISSUE-123: "
echo "Let's go and change the patches"
while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
    hg qref -m "${amendment} $(hg qheader)" && hg qpop
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use mq anymore. Instead, use histedit, commit --amend or rebase. See this [post](http://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2014/06/23/please-stop-using-mq/).